# Showing one-one correspondence from left cosets to the right cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**If H is a subgroup of a group G then there is a one to one correspondence between the set of all distinct left cosets of H in G and the set of all right cosets of H in G.**
The proof of it proceeds as taking a function as $f(gH) = Hg^{-1}$
Why do we define a function from left cosets to right as this $f(gH) = Hg^{-1}$, it looks like this is only a particular case. Why not a more general way $(a)=b$ where $a,b \in G$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Start by understanding why $f$ is well defined. The more natural map $f(gH)=Hg$ does not work, ie, is not well defined. Try $G=S_3$ and $H=\langle (12) \rangle$.

Comment: For any $a\in G$ you can define $xH\mapsto Hx^{-1}a$. The most "natural" case is $xH\mapsto Hx^{-1}$. There's not much more you can say in full generality as simply as this. Also, if $G/H$ and $G\backslash H$ are the left/right coset spaces, they carry left/right group actions of $G$, and if we do the usual way of converging left/right actions we can say $xH\mapsto Hx^{-1}$ is an *equivariant* bijection $G/H\cong H\backslash G$, i.e. it respects the group action.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your "more general" $f(aH)=Hb$ cannot work just because a general $b$ doesn't depend on $a$. One might then try with "the closest meaningful" option $f(aH)=Ha$; but from $a'\in aH$ (namely $a'H=aH$) doesn't follow in general $a'\in Ha$ (namely $Ha'=Ha$, *i.e.* $f(a'H)=f(aH)$ ): for a minimal counter-example, as suggested in the comments by @lhf, take $H=\langle (12)\rangle\le S_3$ and $a=(123)$; then, $aH=\{(123),(123)(12)\}=$ $\{(123),(13)\}$, but $(13)\notin Ha=$ $\{(123),(12)(123)\}=$ $\{(123),(23)\}$. So, this $f$ is not well defined. On the other hand, $a'\in aH\Longrightarrow$ $a'^{-1}a\in H\Longrightarrow$ $a'^{-1}\in Ha^{-1}$. Therefore, if you define $f(aH):=Ha^{-1}$, then for $a'\in aH$ you get indeed $f(a'H)=$ $Ha'^{-1}=$ $Ha^{-1}=$ $f(aH)$, and this $f$ is now well defined.